# How get the values of text in python

Tags: python, string, get

I have this HTML code:

```
<form action="/pe/cart/add" class="add_to_cart_form" id="addToCartFormbt_NE_10677654" method="post">
    <input name="productCodePost" type="hidden" value="bt_NE_10677654"/>
    <input name="productNamePost" type="hidden" value="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK"/>
    <input name="productPostPrice" type="hidden" value="899.9"/>
</form>
```

And I want to get the values ​​'bt_NE_10677654' and '899.9'. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. There are many ways to retrieve data in such format in python

Comment: You can try a webscraper like Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = """<form action="/pe/cart/add" class="add_to_cart_form" id="addToCartFormbt_NE_10677654" method="post">
    <input name="productCodePost" type="hidden" value="bt_NE_10677654"/>
    <input name="productNamePost" type="hidden" value="Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK"/>
    <input name="productPostPrice" type="hidden" value="899.9"/>
</form>"""

soup = bs(page, features="lxml")
a = soup.find_all(attrs={"name" : "productCodePost"})[0]["value"]
b = soup.find_all(attrs={"name" : "productPostPrice"})[0]["value"]

print(a,b)
>>> bt_NE_10677654 899.9
```

Answer (score 0):

u may use the "re" module or if u r scraping this from the web u may see this repo :

[https://github.com/mrHola21/Price-webscraper/blob/main/Web_Scraper/test.py](https://github.com/mrHola21/Price-webscrapper/blob/main/Web_Scraper/test.py)